# Incompatible Pointer Type for Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm getting the error:

```
lab9q4.c:72:15: warning: passing argument 
1 of 'ReadSalaries' from incompatible 
pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
ReadSalaries(&salaries, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~
lab9q4.c:20:26: note: expected 'float **' 
but argument is of type 'float (*) [(sizetype)size]'
void ReadSalaries(float *salaries[], int size)
```

Here's my code:

```
float ReadSalary(int num)
{
    int salary;
    printf("Enter Salary %d: ", num);
    scanf(" %d", &salary);
    return(salary);
}

void ReadSalaries(float *salaries[], int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i > size; i++)
    {
        *salaries[i] = ReadSalary((i + 1));
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const int size = 10;
    float salaries[size];

    ReadSalaries(&salaries, size);
}
```

Comment: It's a good question, but has been answered 100 times. When you take the address of `salaries` the type is `float (*)[size]` not `float **` (just as your compiler is telling you). [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) (**note the exceptions...** particularly the *"..the unary & operator.."* part.) Also note if you remove the `'&'` you have a simple `float *` pointer at your disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void ReadSalaries(float *salaries, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i > size; i++)
    {
        salaries[i] = ReadSalary((i + 1));
    }
}
```

And in the main

```
ReadSalaries(&salaries[0], size);
```

You want to change the elements, not the array, so it is safe to pass a simple pointer.